# Disable adding newly installed applications to the launcher?

Tags: 12.04, installation, launcher, software-center

When I install new applications from Ubuntu Software Center, they're automatically added to the Launcher on the left side of the screen. I understand that this makes it easier for new users to learn how the system works, but I would like to disable that and add it myself later if I want to. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In Ubuntu Software Centers menu bar, you'll find `Show > New applications in Launcher`. If you uncheck that, new installs will not be added to your launcher automatically.

[image]